# Push Notifications to React Native App, based on data from 3rd party API, when app is closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, react-native, hosting

So I'm new to the whole server side of web and mobile apps. I've been doing a lot of research to try and understand how to fulfill my use case for a mobile app that I'm doing in React Native, and I've talked with folks over at firebase and AWS and still don't really have a clear path on what I should do.

My principal issue is this: I have an app that doesn't rely on anything outside the phone itself except for a few 3rd party api's. Repeat: I'm not using a server. These api's provide real-time location data for vehicles (buses). The data also provides info about how long it will be until that bus arrives at a location. I want to be able to send a notification to the user when the data says that a particular bus will be within a certain threshold of distance within a particular time frame (e.g. Send notification when Bus 1 will be at Stop 5 in 5 minutes between 10a.m. and 11a.m.). The user would be able to specify when and under what circumstances they would want to be notified and firebase would hold that information in a database.

Now, I know that Firebase provides functionality for **scheduled** push notifications. I want to do a notification based on a 3rd party api, and the notifications should be able to come in when the app is closed. How can I do this either with Firebase or AWS?

**Side Note**

I personally think that code would need to be running on a remote server constantly checking the firebase database to see if there is a user request for a notification. The code would then pull the data consistently (every 5 seconds or so) to see if the data fits the request. If it does, then it sends back to firebase saying there's a match, and firebase sends a notification to the user. If this is not how that should work, I would love to hear feedback because I'm not sure how to move forward at this point.